# Cannot install docker-engine on Ubuntu LTS 16.04 minimal in LX branded zone on OmniOS

Tags: kernel, lts, docker, container

I followed [the guide](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/ubuntulinux/) on the Docker site to install the `docker-engine` on my VPS which is running in a LX branded zone on OmniOS. Unfortunately, I got an error during the installation which is probably due to the custom kernel of the host.

The output from the installation process was:

```
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript docker, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package docker-engine (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu4) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 docker-engine
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Running the suggested `systemctl` command returns this:

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2017-01-04 21:03:38 UTC; 7min ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
 Main PID: 27548 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

Finally `uname` returns the following string:

```
Linux christian 4.4.0 BrandZ virtual linux x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Is it possible to find out whether I am having issues due to the kernel or something else?

---

**EDIT** A call to `apt-cache policy docker-engine` returns the following output:

```
docker-engine:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.12.5-0~ubuntu-xenial
  Version table:
     1.12.5-0~ubuntu-xenial 500
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-xenial/main amd64 Packages
     1.12.4-0~ubuntu-xenial 500
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-xenial/main amd64 Packages
     1.12.3-0~xenial 500
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-xenial/main amd64 Packages
     1.12.2-0~xenial 500
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-xenial/main amd64 Packages
     1.12.1-0~xenial 500
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-xenial/main amd64 Packages
     1.12.0-0~xenial 500
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-xenial/main amd64 Packages
     1.11.2-0~xenial 500
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-xenial/main amd64 Packages
     1.11.1-0~xenial 500
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-xenial/main amd64 Packages
     1.11.0-0~xenial 500
        500 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: I got the same error, it is because the docker-engine from repo is using `upstart` instead of `systemctl`. Did you able to resolve it with `apt`?

Comment: can you add result from `apt-cache policy docker-engine`

Comment: @Kostanos Please refer to the update

Comment: I have `1.12.6-0~ubuntu-xenial 500`. Can you also add full output from: `systemctl status docker.service` yours is not complete.

Comment: @Kostanos It is actually.

Comment: this is strange, usually some logs comes after, example:

`Oct 15 14:03:52 vrouter01 systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
Oct 15 14:05:23 vrouter01 systemd[1]: docker.service start operation timed out. Terminating.
Oct 15 14:05:23 vrouter01 systemd[1]: docker.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=2/INVALIDARGUMENT
Oct 15 14:05:23 vrouter01 systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Oct 15 14:05:23 vrouter01 systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
Oct 15 14:05:23 vrouter01 systemd[1]: docker.service failed.`

Comment: sorry man, I have different version of Ubuntu, my solution worked for me. I don't have more ideas

Answer (score 1):

It probably happens because you upgraded Ubuntu from **upstart** to **systemctl** (when you did upgrade to 16.04). And you had already installed docker in **upstart**

Removing docker from **upstart** will resolved issue for me:

```
sudo rm /etc/init.d/docker
sudo rm /etc/rc*/*docker
```

After run install again:

```
sudo apt-get install docker-engine
```

And check if docker service starts.

```
sudo systemctl start docker
systemctl status docker.service
```

Comment: Actually the Ubuntu I am running is a small fresh image hence I did not have Docker installed before that and I guess there is another reason why I am struggling.

Comment: try the solution anyway. `invoke-rc.d` is a part of upstart. Fresh image where did you get it from? it may had pre-installed upstart files for docker

Comment: I was looking through the files in the folders you suggested, there are no Docker files in there. Or do you suggest to do this after a first error running `sudo apt-get install docker-engine`?

Comment: can you add `apt-cache policy docker-engine` result on your question?